# ViewBinding in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewbinding

I want to use ViewBinding to work with Views in Fragment.

```java
FragmentBlankBinding binding;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = FragmentBlankBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    return binding.getRoot();
}
```

But when I try to get RecyclerView from that binding like this:

```java
binding.notesRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I get NullPointerException:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field
> 'androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
> com.myapps.notes.databinding.FragmentBlankBinding.notesRecyclerView'
> on a null object reference

P.S. here's fragment_blank.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".BlankFragment">

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/newNoteActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/notesRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where is your xml  file ?

Comment: where do you try to get `RecyclerView` ? it seems that `binding` is null

Comment: Please refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952957/viewbinding-in-fragment

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This working fine for me:

```
private FragmentJavaPracticeBinding binding;

@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentJavaPracticeBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding.notesRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//this hide/show recyclerview visibility 
        Log.d("TAG", "hidden: ");
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks
I called ViewBinding in OnCreate, not in OnViewCreated

Comment: Please do not forget to do binding = null; in onDestroyView()

Comment: If I want to save the state as static, I can assign view binding in oncreate and load some data so that it is not repeated when I call the fragment again and to solve the problem of recylcerView, I assign it in onViewCreate, is this solution feasible?

Comment: No , saving binding in static variable is not feasible solutions IMO, when you called fragment again its re-created means `onCreate(..)` and `onCreateView(..)` will be called again..

Comment: is it important to work with layout in "onViewCreated" ?

Answer (score 14):

View bind in fragment using kotlin

```
class SignInFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var bindingSignIn: SignInFragmentBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.sign_in_fragment, container, false)

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        bindingSignIn = SignInFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        bindingSignIn.txtMessage.text="Sample Text"

        return bindingSignIn.root
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're inflating your Fragment in the constructor, view binding can be done like this:

```
class ExampleFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_example) {

    private var binding: FragmentExampleBinding? = null

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding = FragmentExampleBinding.bind(view)
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        binding = null
        super.onDestroyView()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Considering the below link

[developer.android](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

I prefer to implement it in this way. There is a little difference in limitations for manipulating binding.

```
class SignInFragment : Fragment() {
private var _binding: FragmentSignInBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {

    }
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _binding = FragmentSignInBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this and if you avoid mismatch view error, you can destroy the view after a move or replace the fragment.

```kotlin
class QuestionFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentQuestionBinding? = null
    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentQuestionBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root
        return view
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
       _binding = null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and the best way

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    
    private FragmentMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), container, false);

        // binding.yourWidget.set...

        return binding.getRoot();
    }
}
```

Remember to always put `return binding.getRoot()` at the **end** of `onCreateView()`

Answer (score 0):

For Fragments following implementation of view binding works for me :

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: HomeViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[HomeViewModel::class.java]
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        binding.txtVw.text = menuItem.title
        binding.imgVwIcon.setImageResource(menuItem.iconId)

        return binding.root
    }
}
```