# How to handle click event in viewbinding

Tags: java, android, android-viewbinding

I have a layout with view pager and tabs layout.
Viewpager contains two layouts for  fragments  fragmentpage1 and fragmentpage2.
In fragmentpage1.xml i have an imageview who's id is "myimgbtn"

And i have the following code in MainActivity.java :

```
Private FragmentPage1Binding mfpb;
..
@Override
Protected void oncreate(...){
..
mfpb=FragmentPage1Binding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
 ImageView myimage=mfpb.myimgbtn;
myimage.setOnclicklistener(v->v.setVisibility(View.Gone););
..
```

But nothing happens when i click the image,any solutions ?

It works when i use attribute onclick in coresponding xml layout file.

Comment: Show the full code. From your limited snippet, you're inflating a random layout and setting a listener on it but not actually adding anything to the activity or fragment.

Comment: Did you debug to see if the listener is being called?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution.
In brief i was calling `setContentView` on `mainlayout` and so there is no reference to views contained inside the fragments that it holds.
Here's the solution:
[ViewBinding in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952957/viewbinding-in-fragment)
But the question is what was `myimage` referring to?